# Chrome CORS block for few users and its working fine for few users : Spring boot + Angular App

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-chrome, browser, cors

I have a single-page-app written in Angular that talks to back-end API written in Spring boot.

I am using the below configuration in my spring boot app

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsFilterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilterRegistrationBean() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("content-length"));
        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

    
}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

        @Value("${audience-id}")
        String audience;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            JwtDecoder jwtDecoderWrapper = wrapJwtDecoderWithAudienceCheck(this.jwtDecoder, audience);
            http
                    .csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/error", "/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/test/**", "/api/v1/office/**", "/health").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt()
                    .decoder(jwtDecoderWrapper);
        }

        static JwtDecoder wrapJwtDecoderWithAudienceCheck(JwtDecoder jwtDecoder, String audience) {
            return (token) -> {
                Jwt jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(token);
                if (jwt.containsClaim(AUD) && !jwt.getClaimAsStringList(AUD).contains(audience)) {
                    throw new JwtValidationException("Audience field does not match: " + audience, Arrays.asList(new OAuth2Error("invalid_aud")));
                }
                return jwt;
            };
        }

    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine for me and my team members.. NO CORS issue we are experiencing.. But few of our users are facing CORS issue

I issued couple of preflight requests through CURL command

> curl -i -H "access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type" -H "access-control-request-method: GET" -H "origin: https://ui.app.com" -X OPTIONS  https://api.app.com/api/v1/contacts

It works perfectly fine and am getting the header properly

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://ui.app.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2020 23:23:44 GMT
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 3023da74-f39e-4269-4f0d-abdba6e6cb88
```

But still am not sure why only few users are facing this issue.. Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Only for few users, browser was blocking with CORS Issue and upon investigation, we found that the `access-token` of those users (blocked with CORS) is pretty big (lot of claims within it).. So we changed our token claim plan in our Auth-server and made the access-token get only few claims..

this solved the issue